# Strange behaviour in assigning char**[i]

Tags: c

While debugging a simple shell application, I came across a strange bug when a command has >2 parameters. I tracked it down to this function (string[] is the command line, e.g. `echo one two` and sep is the character to split the string by, set to `' '` where it is called):

```
char **split(char string[], char *sep) {
    char *token = strtok(string, sep);
    char **argv = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
    
    int i = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
        argv = realloc(argv, sizeof(argv) + sizeof(char*));
        argv[i] = calloc(strlen(token), sizeof(char));
        strcpy(argv[i++], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }
    argv[i] = NULL; // sets argv[0] even if i == 4
    return argv;
}
```

It runs fine with <=2 parameters, splitting a string into a char** and null terminating it. However with 3 parameters, `argv[0]` ends up getting set to null in at the end instead of the last element.

Am I doing something stupid or is there undefined behaviour?

edit: >=4 parameters causes crashes the program:

```
realloc(): invalid next size
signal: aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three bugs in your code.

1. `strlen()` gives the string length without the null terminator. So you have to write
   `calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char));` to make space for it.
2. `sizeof(argv)` returns the size of the pointer (not the number of elements) and is constant at compile time.
3. `argv[i] = NULL;` is out of bounds

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split(char string[], char *sep)
{
    char *token = strtok(string, sep);
    char **argv = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));
    int i = 0;
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        argv = realloc(argv, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        argv[i] = calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(argv[i++], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }

    argv = realloc(argv, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    argv[i] = NULL;
    return argv;
}


int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "hello world test word";
    char **result = split(s, " ");

    printf("[0] = %s\n", result[0]);
    printf("[1] = %s\n", result[1]);
    printf("[2] = %s\n", result[2]);
    printf("[3] = %s\n", result[3]);

    return 1;

}
```

I recommend using gdb and valgrind for debugging such problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on these two lines:

```
    argv = realloc(argv, sizeof(argv) + sizeof(char*));
    argv[i] = calloc(strlen(token), sizeof(char));
```

`sizeof(argv)` gives you the size of a pointer (usually 4 or 8), not the number of items it points to.  So when you call `realloc` you're always asking for the same number of bytes, which happens to be enough for two array items.   Then when you have more than 2 you write past the bounds of allocated memory triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Since `i` is keeping track of the length of the array, use that when calling `realloc`, and you need to multiply by the element size instead of add.

```
    argv = realloc(argv, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
```

On the next line, you allocate enough space for the characters in the string but not enough for the terminating null byte, so add 1 for that:

```
    argv[i] = calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char));
```